# Unable to update Windows Patch catalog

Tags: windows-server-2012

Windows patch catalog update is failing everytime and shows up with error

Error Mar16, 2016 7:32:18 AM Error occur: Level: FAILURE
Type: EXECUTION_ERROR
Message: Error executing BLPatchCheck2 (Exit code: 1): Error: 80004005 Could not create the part '.\' of directory '.\': Error 5: Access is denied.

I do have enough permissions on helper server

What do i do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved after reinstalling the agent. Problem with corrupt **rscd** agent in the helper server.

Its strange because i am not able to co relate the access denied error with the corrupt agent.(IBM)